# pandas Why datetimes indices in two data frames are not matching

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is a follow on to my most recent question. Thanks to Bob Haffner I have almost got a solution for updating columns in one df using values in another df.

I have df1:

```
                  shares
trans_date symbol        
2011-01-13 AAPL     -1500
           IBM       4000
2011-01-26 GOOG      1000
2011-02-02 XOM      -4000
2011-02-10 XOM       4000
2011-03-03 GOOG     -1000
           IBM      -2200
2011-05-03 IBM       1500
2011-06-03 IBM      -3300
2011-06-10 AAPL      1200
2011-08-01 GOOG         0
2011-12-20 AAPL     -1200
```

df1 info :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 12 entries, (2011-01-13 00:00:00, AAPL) to (2011-12-20 00:00:00, AAPL)
Data columns (total 1 columns):
shares    12 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes
```

And this df2:

```
2011-01-13 GOOG   0
           AAPL   0
           XOM    0
           IBM    0
           _CASH  0
           GOOG   0
           AAPL   0
           XOM    0
           IBM    0
           _CASH  0
2011-01-26 GOOG   0
           AAPL   0
           XOM    0
           IBM    0
           _CASH  0
2011-02-02 GOOG   0
           AAPL   0
           XOM    0
           IBM    0
           _CASH  0
2011-02-10 GOOG   0
           AAPL   0
           XOM    0
           IBM    0
           _CASH  0
2011-03-03 GOOG   0
           AAPL   0
           XOM    0
           IBM    0
           _CASH  0
             ..
```

df2 info is :

```
 return pd.TimeSeries(index=dates, data=dates)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 65 entries, (2011-01-13, GOOG) to (2011-12-20, _CASH)
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0    65 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 1.0+ KB
None
```

I then issue a df.update command:

```
df2_updated = df2.update(df1)
```

This returns 'none'. I cannot understand why the indices are not matching. I am grateful for any help.

Drew Yallop

Comment: Could you check the type of the first index level `type(df2.index[0])`? I suspect it is not in the same (date) format than the `df1` first level index.

Comment: `df2.update(df1)` modifies `df2` *and returns `None`*. So do not assign the return value to `df2_updated`. Just check that `df2` is correct. If it is not correct, it is probably -- as Romain X. pointed out -- because `df2`'s index seems to use dates (or date-strings?) while `df1`'s index uses datetimes (or datetime-strings). If that's indeed the problem, it could be fixed by converting both the dates and datetimes to NumPy datetime64s using `pandas.to_datetime`. For more explicit help fixing this, it would help to see the code you are using to define `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: Thank you both for your generous help. I have it working now. The problem, I think, was that the symbol list in df1 was not the same as the list in df2. Not the same number of items and one list was sorted alphabetically and the other not (although I am not sure the sorting would make a difference bit I changed it anyway).